# Como exibir um icone escondido, após carregar um arquivo pelo input file

Tags: javascript, html5, input, file-upload

Tenho uma tela onde tem diversos `input type="file"` e estou tentando fazer com que um ícone apareça quando o usuário carregar um arquivo, facilitando a visibilidade de que naquele input já esta com um arquivo.

Abaixo segue as imagens do que desejo, pra facilitar o entendimento:

Antes de escolher o arquivo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de escolher o arquivo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esse é o meu HTML:

```html
<div class="row row-space ">
    <div class="custom-file ">
        <div class="row row-space ">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input col-sm-11" id="ficha_inscricao"  >
            <label class="custom-file-label col-sm-11" for="ficha_inscricao">Escolha o Arquivo</label>
            <i hidden class="fas fa-check fa-2x" style="color:green" id="ficha_inscricao_ok" ></i>
        </div>                                              
        <small class="form-text text-muted ">Ficha de Inscrição Preenchida e Assinada.</small>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Esse é o script que estou usando, nele eu carrego o nome do arquivo selecionado no input(isso esta funcionando) e tento remover o `hidden`que esta no meu ícone e é isso que não estou conseguindo fazer.

```
document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var fileName = document.getElementById("ficha_inscricao").files[0].name;
    var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling
nextSibling.innerText = fileName;
document.getElementsByTagName('ficha_inscricao_ok').removeAttribute("hidden");

})
```

Nesse exemplo estou tentando fazer duas coisas em uma mesma função, mas já tentei fazer também em funções separadas e da mesma forma não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui: `document.getElementsByTagName('ficha_inscricao_ok').removeAttribute("hidden");`, você está usando um seletor de tags html, para pegar **elementos html** e não existe a tag `ficha_inscricao_ok`.

Você deve mudar o tipo de seleção, que você mesmo usou no código anteriormente, `.getElementById` para selecionar a tag com `id="ficha_inscricao_ok"`, ou reescrever o seu código para `.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]` para capturar o `<i>`, assim seu código irá remover o atributo `hidden`.

Fica assim:

```
document
        .querySelector('.custom-file-input')
        .addEventListener('change', function (e) {
          var fileName = document.getElementById('ficha_inscricao').files[0]
            .name;
          var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling;
          nextSibling.innerText = fileName;
          document
            .getElementById('ficha_inscricao_ok')
            .removeAttribute('hidden');
        });
```

O selecionando a tag `<i>`:

```
document
        .querySelector('.custom-file-input')
        .addEventListener('change', function (e) {
          var fileName = document.getElementById('ficha_inscricao').files[0]
            .name;
          var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling;
          nextSibling.innerText = fileName;
          document
            .getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
            .removeAttribute('hidden');
        });
```

---

OBS: `getElementsByTagName` retorna um arrayList, por isso o uso do `[0]`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, pelo esclarecimento não me atentei que estava usando o getElementsByTagName, funcionou perfeitamente!